# Starting Another Activity - Activity not showing my message

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android developing but have experience with python and java, so I decided I want to make apps, thus i began the tutorial from developer.android.com.

I'm in the Build your first app > Starting Another Activity section.

I made it to the final step without errors, BUT the message I type in is not showing up in the second activity created when i press the send button!

(https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage) if you click that link to see the tutorial, and  you scroll down to the bottom, you should see that the message you type should pop up, and with a bigger font size.
The message i find when i type ANYTHING is the small font, default "Hello world!"

Here's my MyActivity.java

```
    package com.example.android.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/* Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void SendMessage(View view) //View must be the parameter of onClick, View is what is pressed.
{
    // Do something in response
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); //A Context as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Here is the DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);

    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

I'm not sure if you guys would need AndroidManifest.xml, activity_my.xml, or strings.xml but it's better to be safe than sorry!

AndroidManifest.xml below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.myfirstapp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_my.xml below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation = "horizontal">

<EditText

    android:id = "@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight = "1"
    android:layout_width = "0dp"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:hint = "@string/edit_message"
    />

<Button

    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:text = "@string/button_send"
    android:onClick = "SendMessage"
    />
```

strings.xml below:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My First App!</string>
<string name = "edit_message">Enter a Message!</string>
<string name = "button_send">Send</string>

<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="title_activity_display_message">DisplayMessageActivity</string>

<string name="hello_world">Hello</string>

</resources>
```

I apologize some of the things are not indented properly if they didn't indent properly when I copy pasted them over here.

If you could help me, I would really appreciate it, so i can continue becoming an android developer!

Again, the app is a simple type a message and send, to see your message pop up with bigger font size in another activity. Though mine is only showing the default, small-font-sized "Hello world!" when the new activity pops up when i press send.

Thank you for your time, and sorry for the long post!

Comment: can't be. you are not using that `hello_world` key anywhere in your code. Try to search for where it is used (right-click "Find Usage") to see how it gets on your second screen.

Comment: @Lal that method is bound from the XML layout declaration (`onClick="SendMessage"`)

Comment: Try replacing `intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);` with `intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");` in your `DisplayMessageActivity.java`

Comment: Also replace `intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);` with `intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);`

Comment: @Lal i was also very confused, cause i figured it had to be a string that made that default be Hello world!, which is why the hello_world in my strings.xml is Hello, i was testing it out to see if that was what was happening, but it still showed Hello World!

Comment: It is actually a string name that has to be given as the first argument for `putExtra()` and it is by which this name, we refer it in other activities..see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra)

Comment: I made the changes to the code. Unfortunately, it still isn't showing the message i'm typing in the second activity. :L

Comment: Your second java file is not correct..many errors..you have wriiten `setContentView();` at the end of `onCreate()` which is wrong.. it should be in the next line after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.. also you you have to set a layout using `setContentView();` and not the TextView.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13485240/3168859) which does the exact thing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, replace

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

with

```
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);
```

in your `MyActivity.java`

as the first argument for `putExtra()` should be a String name, which is used further in the application. Please refer the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle))

Now, in your `DisplayMessageActivity.java`

write your `onCreate()` as follows

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set your parent view
    setContentView(R.layout.disp_msg_layout);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE");

    // Get the reference to the TextView and update it's content
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

and declare an xml file named `disp_msg_layout` in your layouts and it should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:textSize="40sp"
           android:id="@+id/my_text_view"/>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Lal! I really hope these differences aren't a big deal as I keep going with the tutorial. Nonethless, I appreciate your help!

Comment: Graet..:) Glad that it helped.. :)

Comment: `intent.putExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE", message);`. That can not work with `intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);`. The original was ok.